# How can I vote to close a question as duplicate, which as no upvoted or accepted answer?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

I have been trying to vote to close [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/38955/how-can-i-import-sms-from-iphone-4s-ios6-with-samsung-kies) which had a duplicate...

[image]

How did someone originally select it as a duplicate and vote-close?

Is there something that I am missing...?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking ... the question has one close vote because someone cast one close vote :P.  Please also link the questions to make things easier.

Comment: Matthew - I was trying to vote close the question, but it would not let me despite it having a vote on it already by somebody else!

Comment: The vote-to-close as duplicate dialog changed recently. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165933/changes-to-close-as-duplicate Is that what's hanging you up?

Comment: @user1 yes exactly....

Comment: They removed the checkboxes. You need to click on the question you think it's a duplicate of. Then the "Vote" button will activate.

Comment: Which is exactly what I did, instead I got a big red sentence flash up "The question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer", the point being, that somebody else marked that as the duplicate and vote closed it.

Comment: Check this one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165928/we-should-be-able-to-close-questions-as-duplicates-of-any-question -- I was hit by the same problem. We currently cannot close a Q as duplicate if the target has not at least one accepted or upvoted answer.

Comment: @Izzy... [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/165946/139628) *This new rule seems to encourage dupes of unanswered questions, which, if no one can answer the question, means we just gather un-closable questions* that is exactly what is going to happen here on ASE!

Comment: I'm guessing that Ryan upvoted the answer to the other question, VTC'd, and then reverted his upvote.  We'd have to ask him though :P

Comment: @MatthewRead That is actually exactly what I did. I did it because the questions are asking to accomplish the same thing. the one I voted to close, while older, did not have an answer at all. I didn't really think the other had a "great" answer, but it did have one. One question includes the use of kies, but if migration is possible, the use of kies may not be required.

Comment: Is it just me or is the screenshot a bit too tiny?

Comment: @Flow Fixed for ya :D